# Problem in resolving name when connect to mysql container

Tags: php, mysql, windows, docker, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am a begginer in docker and a I am trying to setup the simpler enviroment for a legacy application. I have this docker-compose.yml:

```
services:
    my_app:
        build: .
        ports:
            - "8080:80"
            - "8443:443"
        volumes:
            - .:/var/www
        links:
            - db
    db:
        image: mysql:5.7
        volumes:
            - /var/lib/mysql
        environment:
            - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=phprs
            - MYSQL_DATABASE=phprs
```

And I have this Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:5.6-apache

RUN docker-php-ext-install sockets pdo_mysql
RUN sed -i 's!/var/www/html!/var/www/public!g' /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
RUN a2enmod rewrite

RUN mkdir -p /var/www/log \
    && chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/log \
    && chmod -R 755 /var/www/log
```

And I am trying to connect with mysql with PDO with something like this:

```
$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=db;port=3306;dbname=phprs;charset=UTF8", "root", "phprs");
```

But I am facing this error:

```
Warning: PDO::__construct(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Temporary failure in name resolution in /var/www/src/pdo.php on line 7
... SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Temporary failure in name resolution
```

I am using wsl 2 and windows 10, and I am at this problem for several hours, any help will be appreciated

Comment: Tear down both containers with docker compose down. Try removing `links` and `db` underneath links in your docker compose. Try doing docker compose up. Make sure both containers are running. Go into myapps container by doing something like `docker exec -it my_app /bin/bash` and do `ping db`. If you can ping, try running your app. Chances are high that both containers are in the same network docker creates during docker compose up and both containers can talk to each other. From with my_apps, you can also try `telnet db 3306` and you should be able to connect.